# Service container with simple service object

Tags: php, service, containers

Hello can someone please, give me simple example of service container with one service object (in PHP). To be more precise. How to create service object and how to later call it. 
I was looking everywhere but couldn't find anything that clearly explains me. This is taken from symfony documentation. Best example I found but still don't understand it.

```
use AppBundle\Mailer;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;

$container->setDefinition('app.mailer', new Definition(
    Mailer::class,
    array('sendmail')
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for a PDO "service".

```php
// Run: composer require symfony/dependency-injection
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];

$container->setDefinition('app.pdo', new Definition(
    PDO::class, array($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt)
));

var_dump($container->get('app.pdo')); // object(PDO)[8]
```

Comment: Thank you so much man , its ALOT clearer. Don't want to sound ungreatfull but thought if it can be pure php example without symfony in any case thank you :)

Comment: Here is a Vanilla PHP service container: https://gist.github.com/odan/d4b74104b50279de3e9ed4251ac2335b